# How would you transcribe निताइ ("nitaai") into Spanish?

Tags: transliteración

The Sanskrit word निताइ (English: *Nitaai*) is used to practice visualization based meditation with origins in ancient India.

What would be the Spanish transliteration of *Nitaai* preserving its original pronunciation? I tried Google translate but it changes the pronunciation of 'tai' to 'ti'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Spanish transliteration would be simply [*nitai*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit#Phonology).

- In [English transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration) of devanagari, "aa" /a/ is contrasted with "a" /ə/, but "a" is always /a/ in Spanish.
- Similarly, while "t" is often aspirated /tʰ/ (थ) in English, it is always unaspirated /t/ (त) in Spanish.

Answer (score 6):

Como la primera i es corta y la a, larga, diría yo *nitái*.

Según como la escribiste arriba en devanágari, la t es la dental, sin aspiración, tal cual la t española.